# ckeditor not special character but still encoding them

Tags: c#, ckeditor

I am using the ckeditor  with the specialChars like `'&ge;, '&le;`. But the characters are not special character in HTML, so there is no need to encode it and saving to the database with the string `'&ge;, '&le;`

> Is there a way not to encode the two character ?

```
specialChars: ['&copy;', '&reg;', '&ndash;', '&frac14;', '&frac12;', '&frac34;', '&ge;', '&le;'],
```

Comment: Can I ask why it matters? If the output is HTML, then whether the characters are encoded or not won't matter to how it is displayed.

Comment: I string together different controls like dropdown, checkbox's and the ckeditor. I would like to do one HtmlEncode command